# How i can extract PIXEL from DICOM file?

Tags: c++, c, dicom

I want to write a script to extract the PixelDATA  of a DICOM file using c or c ++, I don't want to use external libraries like dicomsdl... if anyone can help me to write algorithm for extract and show image .

Comment: why wouldn't you want to use an external library?

Comment: it 's the supervisor who imposed this

Comment: I guess the supervisor doesn't believe that "time is money".

Comment: I don't know the file format, but judging from http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page I guess it will be quite a big effort to reimplement all the functionality ...

Answer (score 6):

Just extracting the image data under the pixel data is not enough to interpret the DICOM image properly. You will need other attributes from DICOM file such as `Rows`, `Columns`, `Bit Allocated`, `Bit Stored`, `High Bit`, `Photometric Interpretation`, `Sample Per Pixel` to `Number of Frames` information just to interpret the raw uncompressed image data. Also, stored image data can be in `Little Endian` or `Big Endian` byte order. In addition, image data can be *encapsulated* or *compressed* (e.g. compressed using different compression algorithms such as `JPEG`, `JPEG 2000`, `JPEG LS`, `RLE` etc)) and compressed streams are stored differently than the uncompressed image data. Even the PixelData element can exist in multiple locations in a single DICOM file (e.g. one under the Icon Image Sequence (thumbnail) and one at the top level (actual image).

It can get more complicated when you need to account for `Palette Color` (segmented vs un-segmented), `modality LUT`, `VOI LUT` etc. My recommendation is to use an existing DICOM SDK and there are many open source and commercial SDK available for different platforms and programming environments.